# Assimil Chinese Old & New Editions

Tags: books

你好,

In the 1970's, I believe, Assimil, the famous publisher in France which creates autodidactic methods, hired Phillip Kantor to write the two part textbook "Chinese With Ease," which is fairly well-known and still sold, as it is the only English version of this Chinese book. They recently created a new method as well very recently, though I'm unsure of the year. Having read "French with Ease," the second volume "Using French" and "le latin sans peine," I was wondering about the quality of Chinese with Ease, the differences between editions, and whether it was worth the buy, as I began studying Chinese about a month ago at school, and I've been using Teach Yourself: Chinese for a bit of addition to what I learn in school.  谢谢